# Default save extension is "Normal Text" but Notepad++ is saving without an extension

Tags: notepad++, file-extension, default-settings

When I try to save a file, the default extension is `All types (*.*)`. It basically saves it without an extension, for example, just `new 1` instead of `new 1.txt`.

“Default language” option in Settings → Preferences → New Document is set to “Normal Text”.

I Googled and saw that you can change the default save extension in `langs.xml`.

I've opened it but as far as I've understood the `.txt` file extension is already set as a default extension:

```
<Language name="normal" ext="txt" />
```

What do I do to make the default extension `.txt`?

Screenshots:

The “New document” settings menu:

[image: The “New Document” settings menu]

Trying to save the file and it wants to save to `All types (*.*)`, not as Normal text:

[image: “Save As” dialog]

Comment: sad this is still broken 4 years later

Comment: Ignore the answers below. This issue was fixed in version 7.8.7, so there's no reason to revert to the older save dialog. If you're still having this issue, try updating Notepad++.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Version v7.8.7 of Notepad++ fixed this issue, so try updating Notepad++.

---

If you need to use an older version of Notepad++ for some reason, you can avoid this issue by switching to the older save dialog prompts (this worked on versions 7.3.2, 7.3.3. and 7.4.2):

Settings->Preferences->Default Directory->uncheck Use new style save dialog…

([Source](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13382/having-to-choose-a-file-type-from-a-list-every-time-i-save-something-is-annoying))
Posted by ([Claudia Frank](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/user/claudia-frank))

Comment: Note: The issue was fixed in version 7.8.7, so this is no longer necessary. Try updating Notepad++ instead.

Comment: Sadly the fix broke something else. Now you can't save with an extension that's not on  Notepad++'s "approved list". It will append `.txt` to such extensions... Actually, in the giant dropdown list of "Save as Type" there is an option for `*.*`, but it's pretty hard to find.

Comment: Giant thread about the latter issue https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8398 The dev's (bad) conclusion/reasoning was: "Notepad works like this". But Notepad was really only meant for one type of files.. so appending the default extension in multi-language editor like N++... a bad idea. At least they kept https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8616 open, which is about the (un)usability of always manually selecting `*.*` in the ginormous list.

Answer (score 23):

**New style save dialog has to be set to disabled** for file extension suffix to work.

1. Menu » Settings » Preferences
2. "Default Directory" tab
3. Uncheck "Use new style save dialog (without file extension feature)"

Comment: Seems the default behavior has changed in a recent version. This gets it back to 'normal'.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I set the default save extension back to the `.txt` default?

1. Menu → "Settings" → "Preferences", or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Select "New Document" tab
3. Set "Default Language" to `Normal Text`

   [image]
4. Click "Close"
5. Menu → "File" → "New", or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
6. Menu → File → "Save As", or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

   [image]
7. Click "Save"
8. The file (in the above example) will be saved with the name `new 1.txt`

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Default language is already put to "Normal Text"

Comment: @Larper When you click `Save` it will save the file (in this case) as `new 1.txt` as per your request. Does this not meet your requirements? If not please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1018523/edit) and explain why this answer does not work for you.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @Larper Your question still does not make sense. I already told you the file gets saved as  `new 1.txt`. You **do not have to type** `.txt` yourself.

Comment: @Larper To make your question clear please add appropriate screen shots to your question, in particular those matching the notepad++ ones I have posted in my answer.

Comment: @Larper What is your Menu -> Language set to for your problem file? "User defined" if so make sure it is set to "Normal Text".

Comment: @Larper Have you tried 1/ restarting notepad++? 2/ reinstalling notepad++?

Comment: @Larper Note that changing default extension does not work for already open files, only for new created files.

Comment: My point is that **for me** it still doesn't get saved as *new 1.txt*. It gets saved without an extension as *new 1*. I added screenshots but I can only add 2 links in a post because I don't have 10 reputation. Here is the last screenshot, you can see it saves without an extension. http://puu.sh/mbmMY/fc96875e88.png I haven't tried reinstalling. I will try.

Comment: I have the same issue, see [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/2qkef2Y.pngt). Default language is set to "normal text" in Notepad++ settings and `<Language name="normal" ext="txt"/>` in `langs.xml`.

Comment: @user598527 Did you close all files and restart notepad++ before testing? Note also that changing default extension does not work for already open files, only for new created files

Comment: Yes, countless of times. I've had this issue for months, may have started after a Notepad++ update. All files are saved without an extension by default, as "all types".

Comment: @user598527 Another answer (from the OP) says that a reinstall of notepad++ fixed it for them.

Comment: I will try reinstalling as well. I'm currently using the Notepad++ version 7.4, the issue has persisted over several versions.

Comment: @user598527 I'm running 7.2.2 and have never had the problem (on Windows 7). I'm updating to 7.4 right now.

Comment: This answer is valid... when you apply the answer of @ken. This answer uses the 'old' save dialog in which the missing extension problem is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad 7.5.6 - mar 19 2018:

You have to choose between two Save File dialog bugs:

"Use new style dialog..." setting checked:
Default file extension is not used.

"Use new style dialog..." setting unchecked:
If you paste in the file name textbox a folder path without trailing "\", then click on Save button to set the folder path, Notepad considers the path last folder is a file name (and asks you to confirm for file replacement).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Notepad++ fixed the issue.

Comment: For me as well. "save as" window is now different: https://i.imgur.com/hPN64Fo.png

Answer (score 0):

A fix that worked for windows 10:
File explorer -> View -> checking the "File name extensions" fixed the issue for me.

Now when i use ctrl+alt+s,  it automatically uses the file extension of the file i'm saving the copy of.

Answer (score 0):

Version v8.1.2 (August 2021) was not saving the new documents as .txt even when the "Default Language" was normal text. To fix it, I found the following solution:

- Settings → Preferences → New Document -> Change the "Default
  Language" to another extension like "Java".
- Click Close.
- Open the same settings page again and change it back to "None (Normal Text)"
- Click Close again and it will save the default extension as txt this time